# Set regex pattern that if said pattern is validated in a string, a part of it is replaced by another substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, replace

How to fix this regex so that with these input strings I get these outputs...

```py
out = re.sub(r"(hs|h.s|h.s.)a m(\W|\b)", r"\1 am\2", out)
print(repr(out))
```

Input string examples...

```py
#example 1.1
colloquial_hour = "Cerca de las 2: hs a m, hay que salir antes de esas hs a m"
#example 1.2
colloquial_hour = "A medida que avance cerca de la media noche 12: 04 hs a m. Deben ir a las 15 hs a m."
#example 1.3
colloquial_hour = "A mmm... cerca de las 12: h.s a m, hay que salir antes de esas h.s. a m"
#example 1.4
colloquial_hour = "A medida que avance cerca de las 12:04 hs. a m. Deben ir a las 15 h.s a m."
```

correct outputs:

```py
#correct output for example 1.1
"Cerca de las 2: hs am, hay que salir antes de esas hs a m"
#correct output for example 1.2
"A medida que avance cerca de la media noche 12: 04 hs am. Deben ir a las 15 hs am."
#correct output for example 1.3
"A mmm... cerca de las 12: h.s am, hay que salir antes de esas h.s. a m"
#correct output for example 1.4
"A medida que avance cerca de las 12:04 hs. am. Deben ir a las 15 h.s am."
```

The logic should work that su will do a numeric value and then an `"a m"` replace that `"a m"` substring with this string `"am"` in the original string.

These would be all the possible cases where you have to replace the substring "a m" with "am"

```
X a m
X: a m
X: hs a m
X: h.s. a m
X: h.s a m
X: hs. a m
X:  a m
X : hs a m
X  : h.s. a m
X : h.s a m
X  : hs. a m
X hs a m
X h.s. a m
X h.s a m
X hs. a m

#where "X" is a numerical value ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", ... )
#in all these cases, in which this pattern is met, "a m" must be replaced by "am"
```

Comment: why is the last `a m` in example 1.3 not need to be closed?

Comment: @Alexander because the substring **"h.s. a m"** is not preceded by a **numeric value**, to have been replaced should have been something like this **"1 h.s. a m"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using regex:

```py
(\d\W+)(h\.?s\.?\s+)?a\s+m\b
```

and replace using:

```
\1\2am
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5rsAK/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\d\W+)`: Match a digit followed by 1+ non-word char in capture group #1
- `(h\.?s\.?\s+)?`: Match `h` followed by `s` with optional dots after them. This *optional* group is capture group #2
- `a\s+m\b`: Match `a` followed by 1+ whitespaces then `m` with a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

You could match:

```
(\d+\s*:?\s*(?:h\.?s\.?)?)\s*a m\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+\s*:?\s*` match 1+ digits and an optional `:` between optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:h\.?s\.?)?` Optionally match `hm` `h.s` `hs.` `h.s.`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*a m\b` Match optional whitespace chars and `a m`

And replace with group 1 followed by  `am`

```
\1 am
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BO6z5/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ueA1dz)

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses `re.sub`

```
import re

phrases = ["Cerca de las 2: hs a m, hay que salir antes de esas hs a m",
"A medida que avance cerca de la media noche 12: 04 hs a m. Deben ir a las 15 hs a m.",
"A mmm... cerca de las 12: h.s a m, hay que salir antes de esas h.s. a m",
"A medida que avance cerca de las 12:04 hs. a m. Deben ir a las 15 h.s a m."]

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\s*?:?\s*?h?\.?s?\.?\s(a m)')

for phrase in phrases:
    print(pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group(0)[:-3] + "am", phrase))
```

OUTPUT

```
Cerca de las 2: hs am, hay que salir antes de esas hs a m
A medida que avance cerca de la media noche 12: 04 hs am. Deben ir a las 15 hs am.
A mmm... cerca de las 12: h.s am, hay que salir antes de esas h.s. a m
A medida que avance cerca de las 12:04 hs. am. Deben ir a las 15 h.s am.
```